# How should I prepare my Hens and Chicks to eat?

Tags: food-processing

I heard a [Hens and Chicks was edible](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24584/is-the-plant-hens-and-chickens-edible). how do I prepare them?

[image: Hens and Chicks]

Comment: It's problematic for us to give you cooking advice and then have you eat something that's not actually edible and get sick... or worse. It's part of why we have a [policy](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/discussion-should-plant-identification-questions-be-acceptable-here) of not addressing questions asking us to identify whether or not a plant is edible. If you **know** that it's edible, that's different but it doesn't actually sound like you absolutely know that it is. Can you link to the Gardening question?

Comment: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24584/is-the-plant-hens-and-chickens-edible